# SQL Server 2005 - Reaching Table Row Size Limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sqldatatypes

Is there a clean way to determine the row size of a table before adding a new column to it and not go over the 8060 byte limit?

For example, if the table row length is currently 8055 bytes, and I want to add a datetime (8 bytes) this will go over as it will go to 8063 bytes (excluding the null mapping).

However, if I add an integer (4 bytes), this will give it 8059 bytes, which fits inside the table size (excluding the null mapping).

I am currently able to get the size of the table, however I find it difficult to create an SQL functon to get the size of a datatype (int, datetime etc) and whether the datatype needs an extra byte for the null mapping.

Is there a function I can use/develop that accepts two variables: tablename and datatype:  fnIsEnoughStorage('table1',int) and returns a boolean (yes/no) from a scalar function.

if true, i will proceed with the ALTER TABLE command after the test is determined.

Comment: If one of my tables had rows going over the 8k limit, I would take a very serious look at the design.

Comment: Do you really design your tables by finding out what data types you can add onto them, rather than by analysing what data needs to be stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This query here will determine which tables are potentitally dangerous and have a possible maximum row size that would exceed the 8060 bytes available:

```
;WITH TableRowSizes AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.NAME 'TableName',
        COUNT(1) 'NumberOfColumns',
        SUM (c.max_length) 'MaxRowLength'
    FROM   
        sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE
        c.user_type_id NOT IN (98, 165, 167, 231)  -- sql_variant, varbinary, varchar, nvarchar
    GROUP BY 
        t.name
)
SELECT *
FROM TableRowSizes
WHERE MaxRowLength > 8060
ORDER BY MaxRowLength DESC
```

This doesn't mean your rows are **actually using** more than 8060 bytes - it just sums up the possible maximum size for each column.

If you want to determine the actual currently used size, you probably can do something similar by examining the `DATALENGTH(colname)` function (instead of using the theoretical max value from `sys.columns`)

**Update:** added a WHERE clause to my CTE SELECT based on gbn's response - those types should not be used in determining if the row potentially breaks the 8060 bytes size limit.

Comment: Need to add 2 per variable length + null bitmap + maybe rowversioning pointer. Otherwise this will be misleading.

Comment: @gbn: yeah, I know - but that gets really messy quite quickly - it's an approximation for now, but usually close enough.

Comment: thanks, a best approach is probably the most practical way. I believe the most elegant approach would be to test how much space I have left in the table, and say if it is less than say 32 bytes, prevent the column from being added.

Answer (score 3):

Rows can break the 8060 byte limit because varchar/nvarchar columns can [overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

You'll get a warning but it's allowed.

If you are breaking the 8060 byte limit with fixed length olumns then you have to partition vertically (eg 1:1 tables).

Note that your new int column doesn't go "at the end": the on-disk structure is well defined and data will be moved to accommodate a new fixed length field: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121884/sql-server-2008-cannot-insert-new-column-in-the-middle-position-and-change-data/6121952#6121952) [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793022/how-to-come-to-limits-of-8060-bytes-per-row-and-8000-per-varchar-nvarchar-valu/3793265#3793265)

Comment: I need to adapt my script in that case..... is there a way to find out which columns of a table are "overflowable"? I can't seem to find any indication of that property in `sys.columns` or `sys.types` (I looked for `is_variable` or something like that....)

Comment: @marc_s: Only way I know is from the 1st link I gave: varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant

Comment: Thanks ! I've updated my script to reflect this additional information.

Comment: Hi gbn, I am aware that the variable length fields do not count towards the 8060 limit, however adding a fixed length column does which is what I am trying to prevent to go this limit and throwing a SQL error.

Comment: In hindsight, creating a second 1:1 table does achieve the creation of the column where required, however practically I don't believe I will ever reach such as limitation in the first place. I believe the most elegant approach would be to test how much space I have left in the table, and say if it is less than say 32 bytes, prevent the column from being added.